# How to stop my date from selecting one extra date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the first 14 days `report_date(s)` after a specified date `release_date` that I have set up in separate table. These tables are joined and I can select both `release_date` and `report_date` to show, however when I perform my date function for some reason it is printing back out `report_date(s)` that start one day before my `release_date` (when there is data available to bring out).

This is my current code, which returns me the first 14 days, and additionally sometimes the day before my release date. I can't figure out how to rid it of the previous day.
Where

`report_date < date_ADD(release_date, interval +14 day)`

Any help would be very appreciated!

Image show casing my `report_date` pulling one day before my stated release date

[image: image showcasing my report_date pulling one day before my stated release date]

Comment: This worked, thank you so much for your help! It's crazy how sometimes the simplest problems can get you stuck.

Comment: I have posted this as an answer since it solves your problem. You may accept that as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can just update your condition to -

```
...report_date < date_ADD(release_date, interval +14 day)
AND report_date >=   release_date
```